# Error using JSON to store usernames

Tags: php, json

I am using JSON to store usernames which a user puts into a HTML styled form. This form links off to my PHP file which has a quiz and then the ability to store their usernames. My PHP part for JSON should be just putting in the usernames, I have a part of code which will tell me if the name is already taken and this works. My problem is that it says I am :

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Yoga\examEng.php on line 158

My code is as follows:

```
if($_POST){

if (isset($_POST['firstname'])){
    $checker=false;
    $uname= $_POST["firstname"];
    $file = file_get_contents('data.json',true);
    $data = json_decode($file);
    echo $data;
    if($file === ""){
        $data[] = array('Username' => $uname);
        $encode=json_encode($data);
        file_put_contents('data.json');
        unset($encode);

    } 
    if($file !== ""){
        foreach($data as $userN){
            //echo $data;

            if(($userN -> Username) === $uname){
                echo "<h2>Username '".$uname."' has been taken. Please choose another.</h2> <br>";
                $checker=true;
            }
        }
        if($checker==false){
            $data[] = array('Username' => $uname);
            $encode = json_encode($data);
            file_put_contents('data.json',$encode);
            unset($encode);
        }
    }

}
else{
    echo "Error!!";
}


}
```

If anybody can help I would much appreciate it, or even point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's not 158 lines of code there.

Comment: I was not sure if I should post up the whole file. I will now.

Comment: That wasn't the point.  How the hell are we supposed to know what line 158 is in that code, though I have a great guess.

Comment: Just indicate where is the line. No need for the entire file. Probably where you use array as object `$userN -> Username`

Comment: the error is on this line: if(($userN -> Username) === $uname)

Comment: `var_dump($userN)` and see what you're dealing with.

Comment: @MarcB it is returning: Arrayobject(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["Username"]=> string(4) "john" }

Comment: I'm suggesting to `$data = json_decode($file, true);` and access it as an array. Example `($userN['Username'] === $uname)`.

Comment: @frz3993 that was the answer. Thanks a lot!